# Yarn ignores proxy settings

Tags: jenkins, react-native, yarnpkg

I try to get a build job running using yarn and react-native on a windows 10 machine. The following commands are executed inside of jenkins to prepare the actual build of a native Windows app.

```
yarn config set proxy http://192.109.190.88:8080 
yarn config set https-proxy http://192.109.190.88:8080 
yarn add react-native
```

This leads to the following output although the proxy settings are correct (tried "http://192.109.190.88:8080/" as well):

```
yarn add v0.27.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
warning There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
warning There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
warning There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
```

Any ideas on why this happens are well appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

yarn version 2 requires a different variable name:

```
yarn config set httpProxy http://...
yarn config set httpsProxy http://...
```

Comment: using yarn config list I found there are multiple proxy setting. I remove all and then yarn config set https-proxy http://127.0.0.1:3111 and then its back to normal

Comment: Using https-proxy http://myproxy.com:8080 worked for me. Thanks @Donnie

Comment: That was also the issue on my PC. Several "*proxy" entries. Removed them one by one with "yarn config delete ENTRY" and set them again with Thomas' proposal. Works

Answer (score 8):

Just follow this Link 
https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/config/
and remove the https-proxy and it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and solved by following steps:

Run the following terminal command

1. npm cache clean --force
2. set http_proxy=
3. set https_proxy=
4. yarn config delete proxy
5. npm config rm https-proxy
6. npm config rm proxy
7. Restart your terminal
8. yarn
9. yarn –network-timeout 100000
10. Restart your terminal

it worked for me.