# Yarn Install packages over proxy - trouble with your network

Tags: vue.js, yarnpkg, http-proxy

I'm having a issue with proxy on my work, I've already added proxy config and can run yarn commands such serve.

Now this is a new problem I'm facing, I can't npm install or even yarn install, what should I do to install?

Edit: --network-timeout 100000 don't work.

This is what I want to use: https://www.creative-tim.com/product/vue-black-dashboard

> C:\Users{my-user}\Documents\Github\vue-black-dashboard-master>yarn
> install                                          yarn install v1.22.5
> info No lockfile found.
>
> [1/4] Resolving packages...
> info There appears to be trouble with your network connection.
> Retrying...                                              info There
> appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
> info There appears to be trouble with your network connection.
> Retrying...                                              info There
> appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
> error An unexpected error occurred:
> "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/chart.js: connect ETIMEDOUT
> 104.16.21.35:443".        info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in
> "C:\Users\{my-user}\Documents\Github\vue-black-dashboard-master\yarn-error.log".
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation
> about this command.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631761/yarn-ignores-proxy-settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this `npm --https-proxy=http://proxy.company.com:8080 install package`.

Check out this [link](http://wil.boayue.com/blog/2013/06/14/using-npm-behind-a-proxy/) for more information

Comment: That worked for me since I'm behind a proxy... thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

First check if 'https-proxy' exist in yarn config: `yarn config list`

If not, try adding a new value as follows:
`yarn config set https-proxy http://proxy.myproxy.com:8080`