# Yarn usage error: Couldn't find a configuration settings named "proxy"

Tags: proxy, yarnpkg

I'm trying to update yarn proxy configurations but when I launch the command (I'm on Ubuntu 22.04)

```
yarn config set proxy my.proxy.url:port
```

I get the error

```
Usage Error: Couldn't find a configuration settings named "proxy"
```

---

All of this because I'm trying to run the `yarn install` command but all I get is `package_name can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry` for a couple of packages.

I tried to `curl` some site and it works wonderfully, so it shouldn't be a shell problem (I'm using zsh by the way).

Answer (score 1):

Yarn 2 has different settings:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63707027/7880429

```
yarn config set httpProxy http://...
yarn config set httpsProxy http://...
```

You can also create .yarnrc.yml in the root of your project with the settings:

```
httpProxy: "http://proxy:port"

httpsProxy: "http://proxy:port"
```