# Issue Installing npm Packages: MaxListenersExceededWarning and Persistent Error

Tags: node.js, npm-install, npm-package

I'm facing an issue while trying to install npm packages, and I'd appreciate some assistance. Here are the details:

**Error Message:**

```
(node:1479) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use 'node --trace-warnings ...' to show where the warning was created)
```

I followed the docs, ran npm i -D @waline/client, and got hit with the above error.
To troubleshoot, I started a fresh project with npm init and then tried npm install -g yarn. Surprisingly, same error!

I haven't written a single line of code yet.
The error shows up every time I run npm install.

My Setup:
Node version: v20.8.1
NPM version: 10.1.0

Can someone help me understand the cause of this issue and provide guidance on resolving it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, because of GFW.
You should use a proxy.

In fact, it is indeed because of network problems in mainland China. Even though there may be problems with node. I tested it in Hong Kong and the United States, and no problems were found.

[how to set up npm proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631761/yarn-ignores-proxy-settings)

```bash
npm config set proxy http://127.0.0.1:1080
```

OR:

> A proxy to use for outgoing http requests. If the HTTP_PROXY or http_proxy environment variables are set, proxy settings will be honored by the underlying request library.

[how to set up yarn proxy:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631761/yarn-ignores-proxy-settings)

```bash
yarn config set httpProxy http://127.0.0.1:1080
yarn config set httpsProxy http://127.0.0.1:1080
# You should know the proxy.
```

Comment: You are right. I tried it twice after setting up the proxy: the first time at the company, I still got the error; the second time at home, the error was gone, and I didn't get the error after deleting the proxy. It is certain that it is related to the network. Thank you for your suggestion.